# How to add support of multi-line arguments for Python scripts using argparse?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I've just created [a Python project](https://github.com/ziyuang/scripts-gen) that uses `argparse` for parsing arguments. But it seems that it does not support multi-line arguments. One can check the [`example/command-line.sh`](https://github.com/ziyuang/scripts-gen/blob/master/example/command-line.sh) in the project, and will find it does not understand the following style

```
#!/bin/bash
../scripts_gen.py --template template.txt \
                  --save-to scripts \
                  --param "{'data':'datasets.txt', \
                            'lambda':[`echo 0.{0..9}|sed -E 's/\s+/,/g'`], \
                            'seed':[233,874]}" \
                  --format "{data}_lambda={lambda}_seed={seed}.sh" \
                  --delete
```

Note that this is legal in shell script: one can always write

```
$ ls -l \
> -f
```

in console or shell script file (no prompt in this case). So can I add support for this via `argparse`? Thank you.

Comment: This should be OK.  What error do you see?  You might not need the `\` within your quoted string.

Comment: @SethMMorton In the above example, I will see the Python script can recognize the first argument `--template` but ignoring the rest. Then the shell later complains that it cannot find commands like `--save-to` etc..

Comment: The problem is in your bash script. If it worked as intended, python wouldn't even know there's a newline between arguments--the shell handles that and removes the newline. Most likely there's a space after the first backslash.

Comment: @alexis I was using Cygwin but later tried Debian 7.0 and it seems OK. It might be a problem of Cygwin. But Cygwin can recognize the `ls` example, so it's still a little weird.

Comment: Ok, if the _same_ file works properly on Debian, then it's not a space after the backslash. Perhaps it's a problem with the line endings in your script?

Comment: @alexis Yes I think this is the reason. Since `git` will determine whether to use CR/LF or LF automatically, the pulled script will use CR/LF under Windows, which is not supported by Cygwin by default. The script runs normally after `dos2unix`. I've also found a thread about this Cygwin's default behavior. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin/115223 . Anyway, could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: There you go. With some additional comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Post-facto answer, based on my comments:**

1. The problem is in your bash script. If it worked as intended, python wouldn't even know there's a newline between arguments--the shell handles that and removes the newline. Most likely there's a space after the first backslash.
2. But since the same file works properly on Debian but fails under cygwin, it was not a space after the backslash. Perhaps it's a problem with the line endings in your script?
3. So, the problem was automatic `CR/LF` conversion by `git`, combined with a strange refusal by cygwin to understand the line-ending conventions of its host operating system. Though you fixed it by hand-converting the script back to unix line endings, I would recommend a more robust solution: You could enable CR/LF support in cygwin (since you imply that it is an option), but my preference would be to also disable git's CR/LF mapping. And check that all your common tools and editors are configured to handle both kinds of line ending properly.